# word analogy - accelerate is to velocity as

Tags: vocabulary, analogy

Accelerate is to Velocity as

1. sound is to decibels
2. incarcerate is to prison
3. levitate is to elevation
4. commiserate is to weight
5. denigrate is to reputation

Please choose one option.

Comment: The only I see that possibly works is #3...the criteria appears to be  an _increase_ in a measurement.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question. Proportionality relationships (A is to ? as C is to D) do not address single points, and are often issues of opinion.

Comment: @Cascabel There is not in this concept the idea of an increase but that of a constant level of suspension above a given surface (level that can be changed).

Comment: “Please choose one option.” Look up the meanings of each word and then tell us which one you think is right, and why. IN the question, not in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: It is hard to evaluate this precisely, because acceleration can be a negative quantity.

Comment: This question may be more on-topic at [puzzling.se].

Comment: @LPH I am aware that acceleration can be negative, but that would also mean #5 is viable. Also, _levitate_ means "**rise or cause to rise** _and_ hover in the air,

Comment: @Cascabel Yes, there has to be this initial rise, but then after that, the hovering, which the essential activity, is still called levitation. "Denigrate" goes in only one sense: decrease of reputation.

Comment: ...and constant acceleration eventually hits a limit. I said it was _possible_. So what is the point? It's not a good analogy.

Comment: None of them are good analogies. This is probly an English test, made up by a non-native speaker who wasn't trained in linguistics, for use by non-native speakers who have no option but to take their teachers' and textbooks' word. Naturally, they're being mistaught. So, what else is new?

Comment: Success on local analogy tests such as this often depends on  the ability of the test-taker to get into the head of the examiner and understand what they are actually testing. In much of the Western world, [usage of these types of exercises is  being questioned](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20298577?seq=1)  as many of them are ethnocentric, and ignore cultural differences. The dependence on these types of examining points probably benefits the "American-English academy system"  more than anyone...a system that encourages students to think like the "average white American".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Accelerate is to Velocity as

NB: this is "verb is to noun as"

If something **accelerates**, its **velocity** increases with respect to time.

On a **noun - noun** basis, acceleration is the first derivative of velocity with respect to time.

*"sound is to decibels"* cannot be correct. as it is "noun - noun" but should be "verb-noun"

"*commiserate is to weight*" makes no sense as commiserate is unconnected to weight.

"*incarcerate is to prison*" cannot be correct as incarcerate is not directly connected with prison nor is "incarceration" a derivative.

*denigrate is to reputation* cannot be correct as denigrate is not directly connected with reputation nor is denigration a derivative of reputation.

***levitate is to elevation* must be correct.**

to levitate = to rise; elevation = height

We can levitate to a height as we can accelerate to a velocity (because levitation is the first derivative of height" with respect to time.)

Comment: Yup, (3) is the only derivative in the lot.